What are the easy ways of solving modular periodicity in linear recurrence relation?
I have a very strange equation in my crypto analysis project, which my research lead me no where, specifically
$y_i = x_i | 3$
$z_i = \frac{(y_i*(y_i\pm 1)}{256}\, mod \, 256$
my goal is to solve $y_i \, mod \, 256$ given first 8 bits of a 16 bit value $y_i$.
So i started analyzing possible $y_i$ values given $z_i$ and i discovered this:
0x2f14
0x2f15
0x2f16
0x2f17

...
0x7400
0x7401
0x7402
0x7403

As you can see the first 8 bits of $y_i$ covers 4 values cause by the effect of $x_i |3$ (0x7400 |3 = 0x7403, 0x7402 | 3 = 0x7403), so they are 64 possible first 8 bits of $y_i$ and 256 possible full 16 bit $y_i$ that result in $z_i$, But in that list of 256 values there is a value which has last 8 bits of $y_i$ set to 0x00 and my goal is to find out which one, given the list of 64 possible first 8 bits of $y_{i-1}$, full 16 bit value of $y_i$, $z_i$, but no knowledge of $z_{i-1}$.
for example, i have 0x2f17 as $y_i$ in which 0x7400 is also valid, then i have a list of first 8 bits of $y_{i-1}$ (64 values) in which 0xc9 is among them. I need to find last 8 bits of $y_{i-1}$ (0x08) and get the full 16 bit 0xc908 or pin point the value in the list of 64 that will correspond to 0x7400, which is 0x1900.
So 0xc908 and 0x1900 are equal through $z$, So does 0x2f17 and 0x7400.
Since $y_{i-1}$ makes $y_i$. i thought:
$0xc908 - 0x1900 = 0x2f17 - 0x7400 \, mod \, 65536$
The equation below derives $y_i$ where $c_i$ will always be known:
$y_i = \frac{y_{i-1}}{256}\oplus c_i$
So reversing it to solve $y_{i-1}$ will only give us the first 8 bits.
Please help, even the slightest clue about solving this is really appreciated.
